# KeyError: 'Tipos' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, matplotlib

Pandas is so difficult i have rechecked a million times and my Python file and csv are indeed in the same folder.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(131) #Numero de choques por estado al mes
estados = ['NL','COAH','EDOMEX','VER','TAMP']
choques = [12000, 7600, 9500, 3000, 5430]
plt.title ("Numero de choques por estado al mes")
plt.xlabel ('Estados')
plt.ylabel ('choques')
plt.bar(estados, choques, color = 'green')
plt.plot(estados, choques,"r:*")
plt.xticks (rotation=45, fontsize=6)
plt.subplot(132) #grafica tips de accidentes

Tipos = {'tipos' : ['choque','atropellamiento','volcamiento','otro'],
'numeros': [752, 230,365,155]}
df=pd.DataFrame(Tipos)
plt.scatter(df['tipos'], df['numeros'])
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylabel ('Accidentes Numero de Accidentes en Nuevo Leon')
plt.xlabel ('Tipos')
plt.title ('Numero de Accidentes en Nuevo Leon')
plt.subplot(133)

tiposdevehiculos = pd.read_csv('tiposdevehiculos.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame (tiposdevehiculos)

plt.title('tipos de vehiculos y numero de accidentes')
plt.plot (df['Tipos'], df['Numero'],'r*:')
plt.xticks(rotation=35, fontsize=6)
plt.xlabel('Tipos')
plt.yticks(rotation=35, fontsize=6)
plt.ylabel('Numeros')
plt.legend(['Tipos','Numeros'])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What error do you get? Relative paths are relative to your *current working directory*. It's *not* relative to the location of the script.

Comment: If you're running the script from the same location as the file, try: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tiposdevehiculos.csv')` as the filepath to the CSV

Comment: The part of the error message you're showing seems to indicate you read the csv file without problems, but that there isn't a column with the exact name of `'Tipos'` (maybe in lower case? maybe without the 's'? maybe completely different?). You might want to show us the output of calling `tiposdevehiculos.head()` just the line after reading it. You also might want to show the full error message and trace, including pointing out the line and the command it refers to.

Answer (score 0):

After you created your DataFrame (*df*), add:

```
print(df.columns)
```

and take a look at column names. Most probably your DataFrame has no
column named *Tipos*.

One possible cause of such error is that the title row in CSV file
contains spaces, e.g.:

```
id, Tipos, numeros,...
```

For a human reading this file it is quite natural, but not for a computer.

In such case, your DataFrame has column name `' Tipos'`, **with a leading
space**, but does not have `'Tipos'` column. It takes some experience to
know what to look for (among other just for such details).

Another correction is that instead of:

```
tiposdevehiculos = pd.read_csv('tiposdevehiculos.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame (tiposdevehiculos)
```

write just:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tiposdevehiculos.csv')
```

There is no sense to create one DataFrame (reading it from a CSV file)
and then create from it **another** DataFrame (*df*).

Yet another hint: Your first 2 pictures are created with no error.
So asking this question you should have included only the part concerning
the third picture, even without `plt.subplot(133)`.
Just the code concerning this **single** picture.

And last important detail: Your stacktrace surely contains precise
indication which line of code raised this exception. You should have
included it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what is going on, what line do you get the error? Sounds like the column 'Tipos' just doesnt exist in one of the data frames you are trying to use. Just printing the data frame can help you understand what is in it:

```
print(df)
```